# AWK: Create new columns based on existing columns

Tags: awk

Below is how my file looks like (sorted on `$3`):

```
name_1|G1026|2017-08-27|2017-08-27|2017-09-02|19|19|21
name_2|G1566|2018-05-05|2018-05-05|2018-06-11|51|51|2B
name_2|G2124|2018-06-11|2018-06-11|2018-06-11|51|19|2B
name_2|G2125|2018-06-11|2018-06-11|2018-06-15|51|19|41
name_1|G4391|2020-08-14|2020-08-14|2020-08-20|19|19|21
name_1|G4392|2020-08-14|2020-08-20|2020-08-20|19|51|21
```

The fields separator is `|`. I am trying to add one extra column `$9` to this file based on the existing columns. For multiple instances of names in `$1`, I want to apply the conditions below:

```
cond1 && (cond2 || cond3 || cond4) && (!cond5)
```

Let `prev` and `cur` be two rows with the same first field, a non-empty third field, and `cur` following `prev`. Rows 1,5 or 5,6 are pairs of such rows with first field `name_1`. Rows 2,3 and 3,4 are pairs of such rows with first field `name_2`.

Let `delta = number-of-days(prev.$5 - cur.$4)` be the number of days `prev.$5` is past `cur.$4`.

The conditions are:

1. `cond1 = (0 <= delta <= 2 days)`

   for example, for the 1st instance of `name_1` (1st row), check if `prev.$5` from 1st instance (1st row) is between 0 and 2 days later `cur.$4` from 2nd instance (6th row).
2. `cond2 = (prev.$6 == 51)`
3. `cond3 = (cur.$7 == 51)`
4. `cond4 = (cur.$8 == "2B" || cur.$8 == 41)`
5. `cond5 = (prev.$6 == 19 && cur.$7 == 51 && cur.$8 == 21)`

If these conditions are met then add column `$9` to the first of the two rows so the output would be like the one given below.

```
name_1|G1026|2017-08-27|2017-08-27|2017-09-02|19|19|21
name_2|G1566|2018-05-05|2018-05-05|2018-06-11|51|51|2B|group1
name_2|G2124|2018-06-11|2018-06-11|2018-06-11|51|19|2B|group2
name_2|G2125|2018-06-11|2018-06-11|2018-06-15|51|19|41
name_1|G4391|2020-08-14|2020-08-14|2020-08-20|19|19|21
name_1|G4392|2020-08-14|2020-08-20|2020-08-20|19|51|21
```

The added column starts with `group1`. The leading number increments each time a column is added.

If the required `prev.$` and `cur.$` values were in a single line then I could have have applied the below code:

`awk -F "|" '{if ($1=="name_1" && (($5-$4)<=2) && ($6==51||$7==51||$8==2B|41) &&($6!=19 && $7!=51 && $8!=21)) print $9="group1"}' OFS="|"` file

Any lead on how to solve this with `awk` would be highly appreciated!

Comment: @ Ed Morton, I think @IceCreamToucan deleted the answer.

Comment: Yeah, hopefully they'll undelete it and just add that one extra statement.

Comment: I deleted it because I realized you wanted $9 added to the first of the two lines in the logic, not the second, and going back to modify a previous line after seeing the next is something my answer didn't do. I don't actually know how to do that so I couldn't edit it to fix

Comment: @ IceCreamToucan, I am sorry about that and I truly appreciate your time. Is the question clear to you now? Please let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: Yes, it is clear what you want to do now, thanks. It's just something I don't know how to do

Comment: Is `difference between $5 from first instance with $4 from second instance... is between 0 and 2` supposed to test if there a difference of 2 days between the 2 dates? Your dates at strings, you can't just subtract one from  the other and hope to get a number of days.

Comment: @Ed Morton, yes it should test if there is a difference of 2 days between the 2 dates.

Comment: @D_Stack_overflow Where do these `groupX` come from? Why `group1` and then `group2`? Do you simply start with `group1` and increment each time you add a column?

Comment: @Renaud Pacalet each time these conditions are met, I want to group them. As the conditions are met twice in the sample input so I group them `group 1` and `group 2`. So you are right, I simply start with `group1` and  increment each time you add a column

Comment: How to compare 2 dates in awk to see if they're N days apart deserves it's own separate question IMHO as it's not obvious and easy to get wrong.

Comment: It's kinda irrelevant now since you already accepted an answer but I see you said "the file is sorted based on $3" but it's not. If it was then the 2nd line (the one where $3 is null) would be the last line (or maybe the first in some locales, idk). The reason it matters is that the typical, efficient approach to this kind of problem is to re-sort the input on the key fields ($1 THEN $3 in your case), run awk just doing contiguous comparisons, then sort if back into the original order and we could do that most efficiently if we knew what that original order really is.

Comment: @Ed Morton, thank you for your time and comments. What should I do now? Should I post two separate questions? 1st for calculating the difference in days and 2nd for implementing the conditions on other columns?

Comment: You already accepted an answer for how to do the non-day-comparison stuff so I assume that does what you want and so there's no need to ask a new question about that part. The accepted answer has a way to compare timestamps to approximate days difference so if that's adequate for your needs then no need to ask a new question about that part either. So, ask a new question about either part if you want more help with that part, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following needs GNU awk extensions (`mktime`):

```
$ cat foo.awk
function d2ts(d) {
  gsub(/-/, " ", d)
  return mktime(d " 0 0 0")
}

BEGIN {
  f8["2B"] = 1;
  f8["41"] = 1;
}

FNR == NR {
  if($1 in ts && (f6[$1] == 51 || $7 == 51 || $8 in f8) &&
     !(f6[$1] == 19 && $7 == 51 && $8 == 21)) {
    delta = ts[$1] - d2ts($4)
    if(delta >= -12*3600 && delta <= 60*3600)
      change[nr[$1]] = 1
  }
  ts[$1] = d2ts($5)
  f6[$1] = $6
  nr[$1] = NR
  next
}

{
  if(FNR in change)
    $(NF+1) = "group" ++cnt
  print
}

$ awk -F'|' -f foo.awk OFS='|' file file
name_1|G1026|2017-08-27|2017-08-27|2017-09-02|19|19|21
name_2|G1566|2018-05-05|2018-05-05|2018-06-11|51|51|2B|group1
name_2|G2124|2018-06-11|2018-06-11|2018-06-11|51|19|2B|group2
name_2|G2125|2018-06-11|2018-06-11|2018-06-15|51|19|41
name_1|G4391|2020-08-14|2020-08-14|2020-08-20|19|19|21
name_1|G4392|2020-08-14|2020-08-20|2020-08-20|19|51|21
```

We proceed in 2 phases, reason why `file` is passed twice. The first pass checks all your conditions and stores the numbers of the record to modify in associative array `change`. The second phase adds the last column to all records which number is a key of the `change` associative array.

> Note: in order to account for daylight savings time and leap seconds the date comparison does not use 0 and 2 days thresholds but minus half a day (`-12*3600`) and 2 days and a half (`60*3600`). As your date fields have only a 1 day resolution this should behave as expected.

Explanations:

- The d2ts function converts the `YYYY-MM-DD` dates to UNIX timestamps, that is seconds since 1970/01/01. This is done by first using `gsub` to convert `YYYY-MM-DD` to `YYYY MM DD` (spaces instead of `-`), concatenating `0 0 0` for hours, minutes, seconds, and then converting to UNIX timestamp with `mktime`.
- As your algorithm refers to past lines we use associative arrays (`ts`, `f6` and `nr`) to store information about the last encountered lines with a given field #1 value. The keys are the field #1 values (`name_X`) and the values are, respectively, the UNIX timestamp of field #5, the value of field #6 and the record number.
- As you have more than one candidate value for field #8 we define another associative array (`f8`) in the `BEGIN` section, and use the `in` operator for the test.

Of course, depending on your files, you could encounter memory issues during the first phase. If you have billions of different `name_X` values, for instance, some adjustments will probably be needed to avoid a memory overflow due to the size of the associative arrays.

Comment: You need to add the UTC flag to your `mktime()` calls or it'll fail during DST changes in your locale since the day DST changes isn't 24*3600 seconds long. There's also leap seconds (which just occurred on Jun 30 this year) to consider. Also, if you're considering using `getline` then see awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when/how to call it. A comparison of `if($6)` would fail if `$6` had the value `0`, idk if thats intentional or if you should be using `if ($6 != "")`.  You should mention that solution requires GNU awk for time functions and `gensub()`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your valuable remarks. I modified my answer accordingly, About `getline`. I had a quick look at the discussion you mention (probably too quick). I do not see why using it here the way it is used would be a problem. I am certainly wrong. I do not like the `NFR==NR` trick that looks like a difficult-to-read-ugly-hack to me (matter of taste) but I added it as a second option.

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't like `NR==FNR` then don't use it, use `ARGIND==1` (if your awk supports it) or `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` (in any awk) or similar instead.

Comment: A couple of issues with the `getline` approach - a) if any problem occurred reading `nr.txt` then `n` would retain the same value it had before you called getline and quietly produce incorrect output with no warning. b) if you wanted to in future do something for every line read (e.g. print the current line for debugging), without getline you could just add `{print "Read:", $0}` as the first line of your script while with getline you'd have to do that in 3 separate places (in the man body and everywhere getline is called).

Comment: Asking "why not use getline?" is the wrong question though, the question should always be "why use getline?". awk already reads lines from a file in a loop so there has to be a good reason to not simply let awk do that that'd make it worthwhile to add the extra ugliness of manually calling getline outside of that loop. There are definitely cases where calling getline makes sense but as you can see in your answer, in this case (and most others) your code is briefer, clearer, more robust, and easier to enhance in future if you don't.

Comment: @D_Stack_overflow I added explanations but you will need some understanding of awk anyway. Its man page is very easy to read and quite comprehensive. About multiple candidate values of field #8 I added an example. About the outputs that are not the exepected ones yes, of course, an example is needed.

Comment: @D_Stack_overflow Note that as SO is not a coding service, it is better to avoid extending your question with new feature requirements (would it be in comments or by editing the original question). It tends to lead to complex questions and answers that are less useful to other SO users. Do not hesitate to ask new questions, instead. For your field #8 multiple values, for instance, it would have been better to ask a new question like: "How to test if the value of a field is in a set of several candidate values?".

Comment: @D_Stack_overflow Ooops, there are 2 issues. First the array subscripts shall be quoted (e.g. `p[$1,"nr"]` instead of `p[$1,nr]`). I fixed it, sorry for that. Second, I interpreted your specification "_check the difference between $5 from first instance with $4 from second instance_" literally (`$5-$4`) while what you apparently meant was "_check the absolute value of the difference_" (`abs($5-$4)`). Am I correct?

Comment: I see. I updated the awk script. The first test now checks if the `$5-$4` difference is in the `[-1/2 ... 5/2]` days range. Hope it will correspond to what you need.

Comment: @ Renaud Pacalet, that is exactly what I was looking for. I applied it on the larger file and it works. thank you very much for your time and help. Will you be kind enough to add one more condition to the above code? I know I should ask a different question but I think the condition is related to these fields so I was wondering if you could help. Please feel free to say no. thanks

Comment: @D_Stack_overflow OK, shoot. It'll give me the opportunity to clean a bit this messy answer and suggest maybe a cleaner, single script, solution.

Comment: Hi Renaud! I have a quick question: in case of more than one candidate values for $6 (say 51 and 52) do you think I can simply do `f6["51"] = 1;` `f6["52"] = 1`?